# Proper way to respond to an action without janking paper-ripple

Tags: javascript, css, asynchronous, polymer, paper-elements

So I really like Polymer's for-free `paper-ripple` effects that come with `paper-button`. However, If I need to do an animation (or anything that would block the css animation) in response to the button click, the ripple gets cut off.

So far, the only work around I've found is to wait until the ripple is finished with some code like this:

```
<paper-button id="button" on-tap="_action"></paper-button>
...
_action: function (event) {
   var response = function (event) {
      this.$.button.removeEventListener('transitionend', response);
      //take action here ...
   }.bind(this);
   this.$.button.addEventListener('transitionend', response); 
}
```

But this seems really pedantic. Is there a more concise pattern I should be using here?

Comment: Personnaly, i use a simple timeout :

     this.async(function() {
       //take action here ...
     }, 200);